# DjangoMySQLConverter object has no attribute _tuple_to_mysql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Using the `mysql.connector` package (with Django), and executing:

```
    c.execute("""
      select *
       from shop_sales
      where product_id in %s
    """, [(83, 84, 85, 87, 88, 89)])
```

We get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/venv/dev35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py", line 179, in to_mysql
    return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value)
AttributeError: 'DjangoMySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_tuple_to_mysql'
```

This is reported as a bug at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89112, but I'm trying to find a workaround by writing a converter (from my settings.py):

```
from mysql.connector.django.base import DjangoMySQLConverter

def _tuple_to_mysql(self, value):
    res = []
    for item in value:
        msval = self.to_mysql(item)
        if not isinstance(msval, bytes):
            msval = str(msval).encode()
        res.append(msval)
    return b'(' + b', '.join(res) + b')'

DjangoMySQLConverter._tuple_to_mysql = _tuple_to_mysql
```

but it looks like mysql.connector is adding extra quotes around it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/venv/dev35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 176, in _execute_wrapper
    return method(query, args)
  File "/srv/venv/dev35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 561, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/srv/venv/dev35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 525, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/srv/venv/dev35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 427, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(83, 84, 85, 87, 88, 89)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Connector/Python doesn't allow the usage of a tuple for the placeholders. You need to provide the same number of placeholders in the query: `c.execute("select * from shop_sales where product_id in (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s", (83, 84, 85, 87, 88, 89,))`

Comment: @NunoMariz that's certainly a solution for this specific example, but in general we don't know how many items are in the `in` clause, and since msql.connector lets you add converters for other types it seems strange that you can't do it for tuples... It's handled automatically in MySQLdb and mysqlclient.